# how to get newest/latest record from SQL Server database c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

in my statement:

```
SELECT
    MonitoringJob.ID,
    MonitoringJob.CreationDate,
    MonitoringJob.LastCheck, 
    MonitoringJob.Category,
    MonitoringJob.URL,
    MonitoringJob.Description,
    MonitoringJob.IsJobActive,
    History.ChangeDateTime
FROM  MonitoringJob
INNER JOIN History
ON MonitoringJob.ID=History.JobID
ORDER BY History.ChangeDateTime DESC
```

i am getting from database:

```
7244D096-D388-4216-AE9D-8556F342F0F1    2011-03-17 22:47:15.007 2011-03-17 22:52:28.040 test2   www.spiegel.de  test2   1   2011-03-17 22:52:28.040
6152F7E6-5C4B-42B5-B05B-D3EC43E4B56F    2011-03-17 22:46:59.137 2011-03-17 22:52:27.507 test1   www.ragims.de   test1   1   2011-03-17 22:52:27.507
7244D096-D388-4216-AE9D-8556F342F0F1    2011-03-17 22:47:15.007 2011-03-17 22:52:28.040 test2   www.spiegel.de  test2   1   2011-03-17 22:51:28.323
6152F7E6-5C4B-42B5-B05B-D3EC43E4B56F    2011-03-17 22:46:59.137 2011-03-17 22:52:27.507 test1   www.ragims.de   test1   1   2011-03-17 22:49:27.413
```

i want get just the latest values of CheckDateTime, it is last column in database.
i need just:

```
7244D096-D388-4216-AE9D-8556F342F0F1    2011-03-17 22:47:15.007 2011-03-17 22:52:28.040 test2   www.spiegel.de  test2   1   2011-03-17 22:52:28.040
    6152F7E6-5C4B-42B5-B05B-D3EC43E4B56F    2011-03-17 22:46:59.137 2011-03-17 22:52:27.507 test1   www.ragims.de   test1   1   2011-03-17 22:52:27.507
```

ORDER BY History.ChangeDateTime DESC gives me just sorted values by datetime, i need some different code piece instead. please help!

Comment: the two example rows have different date+times, but all the rows from the original query have the same date. How have you determined which dates to exclude?

Comment: I think he wants the latest MonitoringJob record for every unique MonitoringJobID, according to the date in the History.ChangeDateTime value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT    MAX(History.ChangeDateTime)
FROM  MonitoringJob
INNER JOIN History
ON MonitoringJob.ID=History.JobID
GROUP BY MonitoringJob.ID
```

Comment: hey there are just a id of monitoring job, how can i get other information of monitoring job??

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean - what other information do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you want the rows with the latest value?

```
SELECT    * -- 
FROM  MonitoringJob
INNER JOIN History
ON MonitoringJob.ID=History.JobID
WHERE CAST(ChangeDateTime as DATE) = (SELECT CAST(MAX(ChangeDateTime) as DATE) FROM History)
```

This will give you all the records whose **date** is same as the highest `ChangeDateTime`'s **date**.

Comment: Can you define "newest date" if you want more than one result.

Comment: a last date! instead 4 entries from database just a 2, which are latest

Comment: @Ragims: you mean all those where DATE(ChangeDateTime) = today (or latest recorded date)?

Comment: Change the "top 1" part in p.campbell's answer to "top 2".

Comment: hey tony, but if i will have more entries in database? it is bad solution

Comment: @Ragims: you don't mean "newest date", so you need to specify more. I think you mean "newest date for that URL"

Comment: Hey @Ragims: it is not bad solution, **your wording is not clear**. If only you had said that you want latest results **for every moninoring Job**.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code does what you need. You should group by URL first.

```
SELECT MonitoringJob.ID
,      MonitoringJob.CreationDate
,      MonitoringJob.LastCheck
,      MonitoringJob.Category
,      MonitoringJob.URL
,      MonitoringJob.Description
,      MonitoringJob.IsJobActive
,      MAX(History.ChangeDateTime) AS ChangeDateTime
FROM  MonitoringJob
INNER JOIN History
ON MonitoringJob.ID=History.JobID
GROUP BY MonitoringJob.URL
      ,  MonitoringJob.ID
      ,  MonitoringJob.CreationDate
      ,  MonitoringJob.LastCheck
      ,  MonitoringJob.Category    
      ,  MonitoringJob.Description
      ,  MonitoringJob.IsJobActive
```

Comment: (History.ChangeDateTime) has no clumn name, how to get it?

Comment: MAX(History.ChangeDateTime) as HistoryChangeTime

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a groupBy statement (whatever test2,test1 column was), then call an orderBy CheckDatTime desc and finish it off with a select TOP(1) command.  With the groupBy command you can only return columns specified in the clause, so if you require further information you will likely need to perform a self-join operation on that table.

Comment: @Ragims, You need to do a self join or subselect: select * from MonitoringJob where job id in( ...). As I stated, a groupby only allows you to access the columns you group by, for more information use subselect or for better performance join  on the returned Id's